# Sharing a Nuget.config between Git repositories

Tags: git, nuget

I use multiple Git repositories, each repository containing a Visual Studio solution.
I have a nuget.config file shared by some of those repositories.
I'm trying to find a way to share this nuget.config file between these repositories.
Currently I have the nuget.config committed to each relevant repository, but this means that if I want to update it I will have to edit it in each repository.
I'm using windows, but prefer if the solution could be cross-platform.

Things I tries:
I have read the docs about [nuget behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior), but using a global nuget.config will add these configs to all solutions.

I thought about using a git-submodule with the nuget.config, but that would place it in a sibling directory of the solution, and so it will not be picked up by nuget. I tried adding a symlink to the nuget.config. worked locally at first, but after cloning the repository the link is lost and instead of the symlink file opening the original I get the linking text. (I might be doing this step wrong).

Tech used:
Windows, TFS Git, .Net&.Net Core